# move_uploaded_file() Unable to move uploaded file

Tags: php

I get these two errors when I upload a file -

```
ERROR - 2018-08-15 12:21:25 --> Severity: Warning --> move_uploaded_file(/var/www/myproject/uploads/temp_userscsv/1534332085---users.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory /var/www/myproject/admin/Users.php 675
ERROR - 2018-08-15 12:21:25 --> Severity: Warning --> move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpEWF5d4' to '/var/www/myproject/uploads/temp_userscsv/1534332085---users.csv' /var/www/myproject/admin/Users.php 675
```

To eliminate permissions issue, I tested creating a text file in /tmp

```
$handle = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "x");
if ($handle) echo "Success!";
else print_r(error_get_last());


$fp = fopen('/tmp/test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '100');
fwrite($fp, '230');
fclose($fp);


$filename = "/tmp/test.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

print $contents;
```

It works fine and I can view the file in the `/tmp` folder on terminal too.

I can't figure out why it's having issues with uploaded files? Any ideas?

I have got these error checks in place too which don't register any errors -

```
        switch ($_FILES['userscsv']['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK: //0
                $errors[] = 'There is no error, the file uploaded with success.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: //1
                $errors[] = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: //2
                $errors[] = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: //3
                $errors[] = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: //4
                $errors[] = 'No file was uploaded.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: //6
                $errors[] = 'Missing a temporary folder.';//Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: //7
                $errors[] = 'Failed to write file to disk.'; //Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: //8
                $errors[] = 'File upload stopped by extension.'; //Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.
                break;
            default:
                $errors[] = 'Unknown upload error';
                break;
        }
```

Finally this is my line 675

```
$result_move_uploaded = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userscsv']['tmp_name'], '/var/www/myproject/uploads/temp_userscsv/1534332085---users.csv');
```

UPDATE

Here's the html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div style="padding-left:20px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="postaction" value="uploadfile" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ttoken" value="3525235" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="uploadcsv">Upload File:</label>
                <input type="file" name="userscsv" id="uploadcsv" class="btn btn-default btn-file" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
                <a href="#" title="Cancel and go back" onclick="history.back(-1); return false;"  class="btn default" ><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel and go back</a>                                
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please try short path insted of full path `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userscsv']['tmp_name'],uploads/temp_userscsv/1534332085---users.csv)` where your file exist that you write code for upload or please `../`

Comment: please give us the `HTML` structure of the `form` that uploads the files.

Comment: @ths - I have updated and added form html.

Comment: You only tested the one side of this - what about the other? Does the folder `/var/www/myproject/uploads/temp_userscsv/` exist and is writable by PHP?

Comment: @CBroe yes you are right - it does seem to have issues writing in that folder. However, I did check the owner and group of temp_userscsv folder. It's owned by www-data and has the same group name. It's permissions are 755. What's going wrong here?

Comment: And PHP is running under that `www-data` user? What happens if you change the permissions to 775 or 777 (for testing)?

Comment: @CBroe I tried 777 but still failed. How do I check which user php is running under?

Comment: Sure that path is absolutely correct, no typos or something like that? What does `file_exists` for this path say?

Comment: @CBroe - I checked php user too - it's www-data ( using $username = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];)

Comment: Yes all sorted - there was a typo - userscsv vs usercsv .. I can assure you I checked all these things before posting but perhaps all I needed was a break and check it with fresh eyes... feel a bit embarrased now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to short path of full path `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userscsv']['tmp_name'],uploads/temp_userscsv/1534332085---users.csv)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` prepended to the path of the destination file ensure that the absolute path is correct.

change this:

```
$result_move_uploaded = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userscsv']['tmp_name'], '/var/www/myproject/uploads/temp_userscsv/1534332085---users.csv');
```

into this:

```
$result_move_uploaded = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userscsv']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/var/www/myproject/uploads/temp_userscsv/1534332085---users.csv');
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Absolute path was fine but I had a typo in the destination folder name. :(